# Django-ORM: Count number of groups of each user

Tags: django, django-orm

I know that I can get the number of groups each user has with this query:

```
User.objects.filter(groups__in=Group.objects.all()).annotate(Count('pk'))
```

But something is missing:

The users which are in no group at all.

How can I use the django orm to get all users annotated by their group count, incluse users with no group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Count` method with `groups` attribute:

```
from django.db.models import Count
User.objects.annotate(group_count=Count('groups'))
```